# Exception while creating user in WSO2 via SCIM REST API

Tags: wso2, scim

I keep getting this exception while trying to create a user through SCIM:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(ConcurrentHashMap.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1016)
    at org.wso2.charon.core.protocol.endpoints.AbstractResourceEndpoint.getDecoder(AbstractResourceEndpoint.java:84)
    at org.wso2.charon.core.protocol.endpoints.UserResourceEndpoint.create(UserResourceEndpoint.java:138)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider.resources.UserResource.createUser(UserResource.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
```

I am using JDBC store manager and my request details are as follows:

URL : /wso2/scim/Users 
Payload:

```
   {"wso2Extension":
    {
      "dateOfBirth":"17/01/1982",
      "secQuestion":"What was your childhood nickname?",
      "lastName":"Chandra",
      "mail":"ram.chandra@yopmail.com",
      "phoneNumber":"1111111111",
      "secAnswer":"nickname",
      "ssn":"123456789",
      "firstName":"Ram",
      "prefMethComm":"email",
      "preferredLanguage":"en-US"},
 "schemas":[""],
 "userName":"ram.chandra@yopmail.com",
 "password":"somepassword"
}
```

REST response from SCIM:

```
    {
    "Errors": [
        {
            "description": "Error in adding the user: ram.chandra@yopmail.com to the user store..",
            "code": "500"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any pointers to debug this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: have u tried with curl: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS450/WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+SCIM+Service+Provider

Comment: getting same error with curl. I am actually using extension attributes here. I have edited the question with the full request and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the SCIM claim configuration for `preferredLanguage` was incorrect. WSO2 should give a more specific exception for such issues.